# fork and exec in bash

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

How do I implement fork and exec in bash?

Let us suppose script as

```
echo "Script starts"

function_to_fork(){
sleep 5
echo "Hello"
}

echo "Script ends"
```

Basically I want that function to be called as new process like in C we use fork and exec calls..

From the script it is expected that the parent script will end and then after 5 seconds, "Hello" is printed.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use the ampersand just like you would from the shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
function_to_fork() {
   ...
}

function_to_fork &
# ... execution continues in parent process ...
```

Comment: This is not exactly the same as "fork". I test some command using fork in C or Ruby, and it runs well. But using "&" like above, it fails.

Comment: Nice, but... I generally fail when I try to use a function.  I use a separate script and call it.  Much more versatile.  The redirect and background functionality is more intuitive and can be more easily tested from the command line.

Comment: Clarification for wording: What is described in this answer is essentially executing a subshell in the background. "fork() and exec()" is what bash does every time you call a binary. But this is done in the foreground, blocking the script execution. When you do this in a subshell you get the behavior asked for in the question. See Section 3.2.3 of the Bash Reference Manual.

Answer (score 42):

How about:

```
(sleep 5; echo "Hello World") &
```

Comment: @staticx Meaning that the process will fork, but the parent will not continue executing until the `()` returns?

Comment: @Brian this doesn't wait for me, just forks

Comment: this means that u fork and also track the return status code if u need to

Comment: This is really what you need when you need this.  Most of the time you can just background the new process.  But if you need to background a complex process this is great.